# Add element in massive of objects in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, element

I can not use List type. Only array

I have class Cars which contains an array of objects of class Models.

```
   private String type;
   private Models[] cars;
   private int number;

   Cars(String type, int number){
      this.type = type;
      this.number = number;
      cars = new Models[number];
   }
```

and in models class

```
        private String model;
        private int price;

        Models(String model, int price){
            this.model = model;
            this.price = price;
        }
```

How can I fix the problem with add an element in array. Every time I have Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. I know what does it mean, but don't know how fix it

This is the function for adding

```
       public void AddModel(String model, int price){
            Models[] array2;
            array2 = Arrays.copyOf(cars,  number+1);
            array2[number].model = model;
            array2[number].price = price;
            cars = Arrays.copyOf(array2,  number+1);
       }
```

the line with error

```
    array2[number].model = model;
    array2[number].price = price;
```

Comment: You should use a `List` instead of an array. Then you can just do `models.add(model);`

Comment: only array available for this excercise

Comment: Your exception message says which line of code your error is on. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: array2[number].model = model;
array2[number].price = price;

this lines with error.

Comment: I think the number in the constructor is meaningless. Either you create an empty array and make a copy to a *bigger* array (and then remember to increment `number`), or you allocate a fixed size and don't do any copies.

Comment: @JayCastle When you use `Arrays.copyOf(cars,  number+1);`, the new copy has nulls in all of the locations that weren't copied from `cars`.  You have to create a new `Car` and insert it at `array2[number]` before you can access the model and price of the element in that position in the array.

Comment: NullPointerException means that array2[number] is null, so you can't update its attributes.
could you please log cars. it may be null too wich could be an explanation to the error that you got.